# How to pass parameters present in a jsp page to controller/view?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a jsp/html page in the following format:

```
Name      id       date-Modified       Download
a          1        1/2/3               button
b          2        1/2/3               button
c          3        1/2/3               button
```

So when the user clicks on any of the above download buttons, I want that 
**corresponding** id and Name to be passed to my `view/Controller`.

I am unable to figure out how I can do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ajax,
when you click button,in js function you can get the the row parent which clicked by using jquery ,use jquery you can get everything you need in this row,the make them into object,pass to controller,

Comment: Any links or references where i can refer to?

Comment: @gaurav_setia step one https://api.jquery.com/parent/  to get the row element, https://api.jquery.com/find/ to get the value you want .step two: google ajax pass json to controller or use the value you has got to create url,  in js function location.href=url.

Comment: Thanks  李振纲 .
I really wish to upvote that but lack karma points.

Comment: don't worry ,you know the way to solve this question,just take it easy, step by step.you should learn jquery how to get value .